# Which version of UTS-35 does NSDateFormatter use?

Tags: ios, date, nsdateformatter

I want to use the `dateFormat` parameter on NSDateFormatter (or DateFormatter in Swift) to format dates with a string template such as `yyyy-MM-dd`. I realize this comes from UTS-35, but I'm not sure which version of the standard my OS is using.

There used to be a page that specifies exactly which version of the [Unicode Technical Standard #35](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/) each version of iOS supports. I can no longer find that page in Apple's documentation.

Which version of UTS-35 do the latest few iOS versions use?

<sub>Search keywords: date time format apple nsdate</sub>

Comment: Call Apple and ask them, not to be "smart" but since that is their OS it is there on the Apple site where it is hidden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Date Formatting Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html) has the page I was looking for:

> #### Fixed Formats
>
> To specify a custom fixed format for a date formatter, you use [`setDateFormat:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter/1413514-dateformat). The format string uses the format patterns from the Unicode Technical Standard #35. The version of the standard varies with release of the operating system:
>
> - OS X v10.9 and iOS 7 use [version tr35-31](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns).
> - OS X v10.8 and iOS 6 use [version tr35-25](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns).
> - iOS 5 uses [version tr35-19](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-19.html#Date_Format_Patterns).
> - OS X v10.7 and iOS 4.3 use [version tr35-17](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-17.html#Date_Format_Patterns).
> - iOS 4.0, iOS 4.1, and iOS 4.2 use [version tr35-15](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-15.html#Date_Format_Patterns).
> - iOS 3.2 uses [version tr35-12](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-12.html#Date_Format_Patterns).
> - OS X v10.6, iOS 3.0, and iOS 3.1 use [version tr35-10](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-10.html#Date_Format_Patterns).
> - OS X v10.5 uses [version tr35-6](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns).
> - OS X v10.4 uses [version tr35-4](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-4.html#Date_Format_Patterns).

So you're most likely looking for [version tr35-31](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns) for any of the latest iOS versions.

However, as the [`dateFormat` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdateformatter/1413514-dateformat?language=objc) states, if you're displaying a date to the user, you're better off avoiding the `dateFormat` parameter altogether and using `dateStyle` and `timeStyle` which take into account the user's locale/preferences.

> You should only set this property when working with fixed format representations, as discussed in [Working With Fixed Format Date Representations](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdateformatter#2528261?language=objc). For user-visible representations, you should use the [`dateStyle`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdateformatter/1415411-datestyle?language=objc) and [`timeStyle`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdateformatter/1413467-timestyle?language=objc) properties, or the [`setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdateformatter/1417087-setlocalizeddateformatfromtempla?language=objc) method if your desired format cannot be achieved using the predefined styles; both of these properties and this method provide a localized date representation appropriate for display to the user.